# Open a file in Sublime Text and wait until it is closed while Python script is running

Tags: python, subprocess, sublimetext, popen

I want to open a file in Sublime Text while my Python script waits until I have *closed* the editor. I have tried `subprocess.check_call` and `subprocess.Popen`.  However, the call ends after the file is opened, rather than waiting for the file to close.  How can I wait until the file is closed in Sublime Text?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['subl', 'parameters.py'])
p.communicate()
```

```
p = subprocess.check_call(['subl', 'parameters.py'])
```

Comment: What are you going to be doing that you need to know when the file is closed? Regardless you would need to wait for the child process to finish which is non-trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you just call `subl parameters.py` it does not block the thread, but you can use the `-w` flag to do so. I.e. just call

```py
subprocess.Popen(["subl", "-w", "parameters.py"]).wait()
```

and it should work as requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I exactly needed.